# How to get the id's as output when using for_each in Terraform for Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app_slot" "staging-1" {
  for_each=toset(["staging-one","staging-two"])
  name=each.value
  app_service_id=azurerm_windows_web_app.app82377789945.id
  site_config {
    application_stack{
      current_stack="dotnet"
      dotnet_version="v6.0"
    }
  }  
}
```

In the output, I want to get both slots id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`values` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values) in this case. The return result will be a list of values:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app_slot" "staging-1" {
  for_each=toset(["staging-one","staging-two"])
  name=each.value
  app_service_id=azurerm_windows_web_app.app82377789945.id
  site_config {
    application_stack{
      current_stack="dotnet"
      dotnet_version="v6.0"
    }
  }  
}

output "slot_ids" {
  value = values(azurerm_windows_web_app_slot.staging-1)[*].id
}
```

---